# string splicing in c language, A stange phenomenon

Tags: c

Recently, I saw a C language code, the following:

```
printf("%s\n", "1234" "qwer");
// output: 1234qwer

snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "bvcx" "mju");
// buffer data: bvcxmju
```

To be honest, it's amazing for me. Before that, I didn't know that the strings can be pasted in `"1234" "qwer"` format. Why can it run?
then, I try this 'char a[] = "1234" "qwer"', gcc return an error!
so, can someone explain this phenomenon and explain theory?

Comment: `"1234" "qwer"` is the same thing as `"1234qwer"`

Comment: It's not a phenomenon, it isn't amazing and it doesn't have a lot of theory behind it. It's just part of the C syntax: Two string literals next to each other are trated like a single, concatenated string literal. This can be useful to spread a string over several lines or to create strings with macros that `#define` a string literal. It works when initializing a char array, so your claim about the error seems to be wrong.

Comment: `char a[] = "1234" "qwer";` works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you saw has been part of the C language syntax for a long time. A string literal can be split in multiple parts separated only by white space, after preprocessing and comment removal. This syntax enables for example:

- writing a long string literal on multiple lines:

  ```
  char message[] = "This is a long message that can be split on "
                   "multiple lines for readability";
  ```
- combining string fragments defined as macros:

  ```
  printf("The value of i32 is %" PRId32 "\n", i32);
  ```
- separating string contents that have a different meaning if juxtaposed:

  ```
  char s1[] = "This is ESC 4: \x1B" "4";
  char s2[] = "so is this: \0334 and this: \33""4";
  char s3[] = "but not this: \334";
  char s4[] = "nor this: \x1B4";
  ```
- combining stringified macro arguments

Answer (score 1):

Adjacent string literals are always concatenated into a single one as part of the translation phases. See C17 6.4.5/5:

> In translation phase 6, the multibyte character sequences specified by any sequence of adjacent character and identically-prefixed string literal tokens are concatenated into a single multibyte character sequence.

Formally, translation phase 6 happens after macro expansion but before preprocessor tokens are converted to tokens. Meaning for example that
`sizeof "hello " "world"` yields the result 12, equivalent to:
`sizeof "hello world"`

Practically, this is convenient when writing various "stringification" macros, example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY_CONCAT(a,b) STRINGIFY(a) " " STRINGIFY(b)

int main (void)
{
  puts(STRINGIFY_CONCAT(hello,world));
}
```

It's also a useful feature whenever you have to use hex escape sequences and need to terminate them, since C allows them to be of variable length: `puts("\xABBA")` vs `puts("\xAB" "BA")` will give different outputs.